# Dotfuscator command line

Tags: dotfuscator

I try to use this command to obfuscates:

```
dotfuscator -in:"C:\path_to_assembly\*.dll"
```

But it only launch Dotfuscator GUI with loaded dlls by mask. And do not build them.
How can I run build by command line?

P.S. I use [this documentation](http://www.preemptive.com/images/stories/dotfuscator_documentation/Dotfuscator/Command_Line_Option_Summary.html). Maybe it is obsolete.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is to provide a configuration file, like this:

```
dotfuscator [options] [config_file]
```

According to your example, you are passing in a list of DLLs, but not giving Dotfuscator any instruction on what to do with them.  Use the UI for Dotfuscator to create a configuration file for your application, then pass that file in at the command line.

Comment: Are you using the Community Edition of Dotfuscator?  If so, which version of Visual Studio are you using?  The CE version that ships with VS does not provide a command line interface.

Comment: Also, it appears my initial answer is not correct - the command line you provided will run Dotfuscator Pro with the defaults for renaming and control flow obfuscation.  But again, no command line will work for the CE version.